# Changing YAML file without restarting Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

I want to be able to edit a `YAML` file and reload it in a ***Rails 4*** app. Right now I am loading the `YAML` file via an `initializer`, and I know that this will load the file only once and a restart will be required after changing it.

How could I accomplish a `YAML` reloading/refreshing as it is accomplished via `i18n YAML` files in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the file, I assume you assign it to some variable or constant. If instead you don't assign it, then the load will be performed every time.

Instead of:

```
CONTENT = Yaml.load_file('your_file.yml')
```

create a simple class or function:

```
module YourFileReader
  def self.load
    Yaml.load_file('your_file.yml')
  end
end
```

and use the defined method to read the file in your app

```
YourFileReader.load
```

or even simpler, use

```
Yaml.load_file('your_file.yml')
```

directly in your app where you need to read the file.

Comment: Possibly not perfect, you will load the file and parse it on every request which calls `YourFileReader.load`. Considering disk IO is often the biggest bottleneck this could lead to serious regressions on a busy site. See my solution for one way to reload and reparse the file only on file change.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something in the lines of checking for file's change time, for example:

```
module MyFileReader
  def self.my_yaml_contents
    if @my_yaml_file_ctime != File.ctime(file_name)
      @my_yaml_contents = YAML.load(File.open(file_name))
      @my_yaml_file_ctime = File.ctime(file_name)
    end
    @my_yaml_contents
  end
end
```

`MyFileReader.my_yaml_contents` method will load and parse the file only on startup and change and serve the already parsed data in the meantime,

see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-ctime

Comment: You right about the bottleneck ;-) thanks for the answer @bbozo

Comment: Hey this does not seem to work, further would you not want to use mtime to actually check for modified?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `require` use `load` to load the file.

`require` will load files only once. But `load` will load when it is called.

See more about this here http://ionrails.com/2009/09/19/ruby_require-vs-load-vs-include-vs-extend/